# Kmix Muting Sound, Choosing Wrong Device, Crashing

Tags: sound

I'm running 12.04 with KDE.  Not Kubuntu. KMix is misbehaving.

The volume control is resetting itself to zero volume.  The speaker icon is marked red.  Kmix produces the following when I run it in a terminal:

```
`enter code here`QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.`
```

Kmix does not launch after that.

I use the "Default Audio" on the board.  There is also HDMI audio I don't use.  Kmix wants to use HDMI.  When I set "Default Audio" as preferred, it reverts back to HDMI.

When this happens, alsamixer shows all channels have been muted. I can unmute them, but "alsactl store 0" produces this: "Home directory /home/abcdefg not ours"

Answer (score 3):

OP posted:

> Per [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=657373) report at Fedora, I edited /etc/pulse/daemon.conf to change "flat-volumes = no" to "flat-volumes = yes". I then logged off and back on and the audio mutes were gone.